# Images not fitting in div

Tags: html, css

I have a row of 4 images that are inside a div, but the width of the images don't fit even though `.productBox img` is set to `width:auto`. It's still overflowing on the side.
[image]

I've been playing with it for awhile, but haven't got it to fit correctly. I created a stackblitz as well to share: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-dx6p1z

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `object-fit: cover; max-width: 100%;` to `.productBox img`, this will make the image stay in the box and make sure that it wont shrink in a weird way.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Bootstrap in your project, giving the bootstrap class img-fluid to all the images will make them fit in the div. Try giving the class img-fluid like this to image tag:

```
<div class="productBox"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{img}}" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
.productBox img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
 }
```

The `max-width: 100%` on an image scales it horizontally to fit its parent container also preventing it to be cut off, then height auto would scale it vertically to match its width. `max-height: 200px` would prevent the image from having the height greater than 200 at all times. Thus, aligning all boxes with images to the same height.